# bounds.size cannot get the correct real time size

Tags: ios, cgsize

I have a UIView object in a view controller and wanna add a CALayer object into the UIView object.
The auto layout configuration of the UIView object is shown as follows. (Sorry I cannot embed pix yet, please click the links instead)
[Link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bHTR.png)
[Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiOIi.png) (the gray rect is the UIView object)

I set the size of the CALayer object (myCAlayer) and added it to the UIView object (myUIView) via the following codes.

```
myCALayer.frame = myUIview.layer.bounds
myUIview.layer.addSublayer(myCALayer)
```

I expected that muCALyer can exactly fill myUIView.
However, please refer to ttp://imgur.com/V4AN1Uy (sorry, please manually open this link cuz I can not post more than 2 links),
myCALayer (the gray range) went beyond myUIView (the green line).

By `po myUIview.layer.bounds`, I found that the CGSize is:

> size : CGSize*
>      - width : 500.0
>      - height : 380.0

where it seems that the width=500 was calculated from 600-2*50 (600 is the default width of the view controller under auto layout), but rather than the actual width of myUIView when the app was running.  The actual one should be much narrower.  Also, the height has the same problem.

Is there any way to obtain the actual width/height? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved.

```
myCALayer.frame = myUIview.layer.bounds
myUIview.layer.addSublayer(myCALayer)
```

The problem resides in that the code above was in viewDidLoad() method.
However it seems that it should be moved to viewDidAppear().  Now the issue is fixed.

Maybe it is because the layout is not finished yet in viewDidLoad() but is finished in viewDidAppear().